# Turning list to dictionary with strings as keys and floats as list of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
['dave', 78132168.51, 76751343.32, 'john', 2779712.24, 2042429.65, 2224123.33, 'mark', 20795797.19, 22111378.59]
```

I want to create a dic that uses string items as keys and subsequent float items as values, in a way it looks like this:

```
{'dave': [78132168.51, 76751343.32], 'john': [2779712.24, 2042429.65, 2224123.33], 'mark':[20795797.19, 22111378.59]}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you imagine are the logical steps in the procedure to do this? What part can't you do yourself? To be clear: the rule that tells you where to stop each list value and read the next key, is simply based on the data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
lst = ['dave', 78132168.51, 76751343.32, 'john', 2779712.24, 2042429.65, 2224123.33, 'mark', 20795797.19, 22111378.59]

d = dict()
for item in lst:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        current_key = item
    if isinstance(item, float):
        if current_key not in d:
            d[current_key] = [item]
        else:
            d[current_key].append(item)

print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'dave': [78132168.51, 76751343.32], 'john': [2779712.24, 2042429.65, 2224123.33], 'mark': [20795797.19, 22111378.59]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = {}
for val in flatlist:
    if type(val) == 'str':
        key = val
        result[key] = []
    else
        result[key].append(val)
```

Something like this

Answer (score 1):

```
data = { your_data }
result = {}
for item in data:
    if isinstance(item,str): # Is it a key or a value?
        key = item # Remember the new key
        result[key] = [] # Initialize a list
    else:
        result[key].append(item) # Append the value

# {'dave': [78132168.51, 76751343.32], 'john': [2779712.24, 2042429.65, 2224123.33], 
#  'mark': [20795797.19, 22111378.59]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It goes through list. If name is found - the next found items appends to this result_dict[name]

```
orig = ['dave', 78132168.51, 76751343.32, 'john', 2779712.24, 2042429.65, 2224123.33, 'mark', 20795797.19, 22111378.59]

result_dict = dict()
name = None
for item in orig:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        name = item
        result_dict[name] = []
    else:
        result_dict[name].append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method. We simply check if the value is a string or not and proceed accordingly.

**If it is a string:**

- create a `list` in the `database` with the string as the key
- use a walrus (`:=` ~ py 3.8+) to store the name for the next iteration
- skip the rest of the loop for this iteration.

**If it isn't a string**

- skip all of the string logic
- append the current item to the `database` under the name we stored.

**Example:**

```
data = ['dave', 78132168.51, 76751343.32, 'john', 2779712.24, 2042429.65, 2224123.33, 'mark', 20795797.19, 22111378.59]

database = dict()
name = ''

for item in data:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        database[(name := item)] = []
        continue
        
    database[name].append(item)
    
print(database)
```

Comment: Note: ``:=`` requires python 3.8+